# CORS - multiple values in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: apache, vue.js, cors, axios

I've tried to fetch data from Wordpress API in Vue App.
I am using DigitalOcean with Apache.

I've set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in vhost.

But now I've got an error like this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at xxx from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, *', but only one is allowed.

I am using axios for requests.

Do you have any ideas what's going on?
Is it server side issue or should I set something in axios config?

Thanks.

Comment: Is everything working as expected now?

Answer (score 0):

This is a server-side issue. You need to enable CORS in your apache config, by either:

1. Setting `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` - meaning that all origins are allowed to make requests to this server
2. Setting `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"`

This tells the server to accept requests from this origin(s), to further explain.

https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your header set statement to:

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Otherwise Apache will prepend origin in request to the header, which causes the issue.